# Why do the properties in my code not work?

Tags: c#, interface, properties, polymorphism

I have created an interface and then derived a class from it:

```
 public interface Ishape
{
    void draw();
    int Number { get; set; }
}
class Circle : Ishape
{
    public Circle(int a)
    {
        number = a;
    }
    public void draw()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Circle.");
    }
    private int number;

    public int Number
    {
        get
        {
            return number;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value < -5)
                number = -5;
        }
    }
    public int GetNumber()
    {
        return number; 
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Circle a1 = new Circle(-6);
        Console.WriteLine(a1.GetNumber());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

As you can see, there is an autoproperty in the interface. I then decided to create a property in the new class that derived from the interface that would set the variable "number" to -5 if the value is less than -5. For some reason, the property does not seem to be working. Using the constructor, I set the value of the variable to -6, and the property did not change the value to -5. Why?

Comment: Because you set `number` field, not the `Number` property and you validation logic isn't called. You can spend some time to debug your code and find it by yourself

Comment: The logic in your property seems odd.  You either set the backing field to -5 or you don't change the current value at all, maybe you actually want `number = value < -5 ? -5 : value;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are setting number = a and not Number = a in your constructor.
 Try this:

---

```
 public Circle(int a)
{
    Number = a;
}
```

Comment: You are welcome :) Don't forget to accept the answer. Thanks. Happy coding !

Answer (score 1):

Your `Number` Property is never actually `set`.

In your `Circle` constructor, change `number` to `Number`.

```
public Circle(int a)
{
    Number = a;
}
```

Also, if you intend to use GetNumber as your publicly available `get` (and nothing more), then I would advise that you change the access modifier for your `Number` property in your `Circle` class.